# Using "an out of line train" to describe a train which is going out of rails

Tags: phrase-request

I want to describe a train which is going out of rails. In Farsi/Persian language we say an "out of line train" but I am not sure about English. I found something about out of rails not out of line or lines. Also, there is a doubt that can I use it for broken trains too which are not in use anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are referring to a train that is being removed from service, and not to a train that has [derailed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/derail) from the tracks. If I'm right about that, then the word [**decommissioned**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/decommissioned) might apply:

> **decommission** (*v.*) to stop using something such as a weapon, ship, or nuclear power station [(Macmillan)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/decommission)

If you are instead referring to a train that is off the tracks (due to a mechanical malfunction), you would say the train has **derailed**, or is **off the tracks**, or is **off the rails**, although that last expression is also a [euphemism for "going insane"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-the-rails), much like *off his rocker*. As Ozzy Ozbourne sang: *"I'm going off the rails on a crazy train!"*

Comment: Can I use "out of line" train for a train that has derailed from tracks? And thanks for suggesting decommissioned for a train is being removed from service.

Comment: @user37324 -- I doubt that a native speaker of US English would immediately understand "out of line" for a train that is off the tracks.  (I understand "out of line" usually to mean "misbehaving", which wouldn't be applicable to a train or other inanimate object.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! As I said it is a Persian term and I translated it word by word in English to find if it makes sense or not and found it.