# I have "a doubt" about whether this phrase is acceptable English

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, questions

To my (British) ear, it never sounds correct to say you *have **a doubt** about something*.

I expect that *doubt* to be pluralised, even if there's only one specific thing that I'm doubtful of, in one specific way, so I would always say *"I have **doubts** about something"*.

Answers to [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/) say that using *doubt* as a synonym for *question* is "Indian English". That seems to be the case in [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/correct-usage-of-clauses-referring-to-subject-and-object) which starts with *"I have a doubt on my construction"*, because the OP really is saying *"I have a question"* (which he goes on to actually ask). Okay, it should have been *a question/doubt **about** something*, not ***on***, but I'm not concerned with that detail here.

But in [another ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/using-an-out-of-line-train-to-describe-a-train-which-is-going-out-of-rails) the OP says *"...there is a doubt that can I use [some construction]"*. In that case it's not easy to see how the word *doubt* can be replaced with *question*.

I don't have a problem with, for example, ["The reason for my doubt is [some reason]"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20has%20a%20doubt%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22reason%20for%20my%20doubt%20is%22&oq=%22reason%20for%20my%20doubt%20is%22&gs_l=serp.3...26151.30589.1.30836.16.16.0.0.0.0.85.893.16.16.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.WREd6QiSNgI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=935), because there I interpret it as *doubt=uncertainty* (a state of mind, syntactically equivalent to words like *happiness, agitation, sorrow*, etc.). But you certainly can't *"have a happiness about something"*. So my question is...

> Is it acceptable today to use singular noun ***doubt*** in any contexts where it means something other than *state of mental uncertainty*? If so, what are those contexts?

Comment: your title is at odds with your question in that the title is a self-referential sentence about a state of mental uncertainty, which you specifically exclude from the question.

Comment: Doesn't _doubt_ just mean "a feeling of being uncertain about something or not believing something"?

Comment: I've now read the word doubt so often and in quick succession that it doesn't look like a real word to me anymore. *Dauw-bt*? ;) At any rate: my instinct as a native speaker is to agree with you, but I can't venture to explain why.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Maybe that's the "crossover point" in meaning (I think *you* sometimes write *"I have a doubt"*). But from my point of view, that's like saying ***happiness*** means "a feeling of being happy". Which doesn't work for me as a native speaker (you'd have to at least say *happiness* is ***the** feeling you have when you are happy*, or something). It's not so much the definition - it's the grammar of how we can use the word. Or maybe there's some subtle semantic distinction I can't put my finger on, I don't know.

Comment: Just to throw a little extra confusion in there, "without a doubt" is a correct construction. Of course, this does simply mean "without confusion", but it is a noun usage. (It's also a colloquial phrase, so rules don't exactly apply with certainty.)

Comment: @Jonathan Garber: I'm going to stick my neck out and say *"Without [a] doubt"* and *"No doubt"* are "set phrases" as per user3169's answer. They don't conform to a coherent set of grammatical principles linked to the near-synonym *"question"*. Note that you can say *"Without question"*, but so far as I know, native speakers today never say *"Without **a** question"*.

Comment: Are you sure? I haz a dou--ohwait. But you're right, it's the different usage contexts that obscured it in my mind. ("Without a doubt" is rarely used sarcastically, while "no doubt" frequently is.)

Comment: The use never bothered me until now. *OED 1* calls it obsolete, so I guess I should stop.

Comment: @StoneyB: Ah - I see OED online has *2. A matter or point involved in uncertainty; a doubtful question; a difficulty. **Obs.*** Perhaps that's the usage that survived in India, and maybe other non-native speakers pick up on it because their own language happens to have a single word functioning the way *question* and *doubt* work in English. Interestingly, [*allay my **doubts***](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22allay+my+doubts%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) has a claimed 1840 hits in Google Books, but *allay my **doubt*** has only 30.

Comment: Well, *OED 1* gives no citation more recent than 1693, so I'm feeling really obsolete myself for using it. I must pretend that it comes of my intimate familiarity with 17th century drama.

Comment: @StoneyB: Could be. I must say that in general your "feel" for "standard current usage" often seems closer to my own than most Americans, so your *"never bothered me until now"* did surprise me a bit. It's also possible the usage survived longer in the US after it became obsolete in the UK, *and* that it's been kept alive/resurrected by the fact that AmE is in many respects more "cosmopolitan" than BrE today (more immigrant non-native speakers over [relatively] recent generations, skewing the ongoing syntactic changes in peculiar ways).

Comment: Well, my literary taste has always been British rather than US - I grew up on Kipling, Buchan, Wodehouse, Dickens, did my academic and theatre work almost entirely in British drama: I've done more productions of Pinter than of all American playwrights combined. And my native GS dialect is conservative and, I fear, dying.

Comment: I have my doubts over whether "doubt" is a count noun, or an almost-always plural mass noun.

Comment: @Peter: I certainly haven't got [**a misgiving**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+misgiving%2Cmy+misgivings&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) about that! :)

Comment: @WendiKidd - and for that reason and others, doubtless, please migrate the Q to ELU!

Comment: Since it's *my* question, Wendikidd, I hope I get a say in that. And I *don't* want it migrated. @martin: - [a similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/) was asked on ELU years ago, as referenced in my question text. The honest truth is I'm quite clear on what ***I*** think are acceptable usages of singular "doubt" today, so to some extend I posed a "rhetorical question" here. No disrespect to speakers of Indian English, but I wanted ELL to include a question clarifying the situation for other *learners*.

Comment: @martin I'm afraid I don't see a reason to migrate this question. If you doubt this question's topicality here, you're more than welcome to raise the issue on meta. If you can explain your reasoning and garner significant community support, I'd be happy to reconsider.

Comment: Just seemed a bit advanced for here, especially with similar, or more basic Qs remaining on ELU. No problem; the more overlap there is, the reason to merge the two sites.

Comment: @martin: Well, Wendikidd's a mod here, and I've always been a solid supporter of separating the "learner" stuff from the "interesting to competent speakers" stuff. So neither of *us* are likely to buy your "overlap = reason to merge" line. It's here because I think learners who happen to have had more exposure to "Indian" than "standard" English should be aware of this usage difference. Obviously *native* speakers of IE will simply speak as they do, but others may well prefer not to find themselves unwittingly committed to a "marked" form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because *doubt* is an old word (the OED attests it from 1225) there are a number of nuances of meaning. In summary, with my numbers not OED's:

> 1. A subjective state of uncertainty about the truth or reality of something;
> 2. (plural) A feeling of uncertainty as to something;
> 3. The condition of being objectively uncertain;
> 4. A state of affairs which gives rise to uncertainty;
> 5. A matter or point involved in uncertainty; a difficulty (Obsolete);
> 6. Apprehension, dread, fear (Obsolete);
> 7. A thing to be dreaded; danger, risk (Obsolete).

As a singular noun, it is decidedly abstract and refers to a **state of being.** Thus one can be ***in doubt*** about something. As a mass noun referring to a state of being, *doubt* would not normally be pluralised.

When it refers to a particular feeling of uncertainty it **is** pluralised. Thus if one has that feeling, one ***has doubts.*** One does not "have a doubt" because the singular *doubt* refers to a state of being; senses 5, 6 and 7 which refer to particular *things* are obsolete in Standard English.

The uses which are obsolete in Standard English may have survived or been resurrected in other dialects. The [ELU references](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/) say that it does occur in Indian English.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't grate on my American ear. Though I'll concede that *I have doubts* sounds better, I had to think about it.

I checked my usual sources: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20doubts%20about,have%20a%20doubt%20about&year_start=1925&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3) and [Google books](https://www.google.com/#q=%22have+a+doubt+about%22&start=50&tbm=bks), and concluded:

- The (perhaps more technically correct) *I have doubts* is more common, though both can be found.
- The Ngram for British English has a perceptibly flatter line, so it may be a bit more common in the US than in the UK.
- I did find this except in parliamentary debates (although the excerpt does not indicate who is speaking):

> I wish to see legislation that works. At the moment **I have a doubt about its workability**. I have asked this question before to the noble Baroness, Lady Scotland .. and I did not receive an answer.

(maybe she snubbed him because he said "I have a doubt" – who knows?)

<sub>Source: The Parliamentary Debates (Hansard): Official Report, Volume 674
Great Britain. Parliament. House of Lords, 2005</sub>

---

#### EDIT:

(to FumbleFingers and the downvoter, who may not be one in the same)

Okay, I didn't want to have to do this, as I included some links for the curious to explore. However, if more samples are needed to thwart the downvoting, so be it:

> ***I have a doubt about this story**. Whereas Holt has displaced the nationalist preoccupation with whether freedom was given or taken he nevertheless reproduces a story about the ultimate failure of the liberal emancipation project to confer substantive freedoms*.
>
> > – quote taken from *Refashioning Futures: Criticism after Postcoloniality*, by David Scott, 1999. Yes, Scott did write a book covering Mother Teresa – maybe that's where he picked up this horrible English phrase? – but he was born in Ohio, attended seminary in Pennsylvania, and he recently served a two-year stint as editor in chief of the Catholic News Agency.

---

> *You owe it not to modern science, but to ancient superstition. Had they not obligingly provided the commandment, it were vain for you to provide the camera. Besides, **I have a doubt** about this scientific superiority of fire-arms*...
>
> > – quote taken from *The Scientific Mind*, a 1927 short story by G.K. Chesterton. Yes, in the excerpt, the cook is talking to the professor, not the other way around, but I don't think Chesterton is trying to make the cook sound ignorant or uneducated.

---

> *It isn't always possible to know why a given sentence in your overview isn't effective, but if you suspect a given sentence isn't strong **or if you have a doubt about** whether a given idea is a plus, rethink and revise the material in question*.
>
> > – quote taken from *The Art of the Book Proposal*, described by the publisher as "an expert's guide through the elements of a nonfiction book proposal." It was written by Eric Maisel, an American author who has written more than 40 books.

---

> *There is nothing that intercessory prayer cannot do. Oh, believer, you have a might engine in your hand, so use it. Use it constantly, use it now in faith, and you shall surely prevail. But **perhaps you have a doubt about** interceding for someone who has fallen far into sin.*
>
> > – quote taken from *Intercessory Prayer*, a sermon delivered by Charles Spurgeon, British theologian and preacher. Excepted from the book *Spurgeon on Prayer*. I will grant that the language is flowery, designed to be spoken from the pulpit in the 1800s; nonetheless, I have no more problem with Spurgeon saying "have a doubt about" than I do with him starting the sentence with a preposition.

---

> *Analogously, Cicero **does not have a doubt about** the immortality of the soul, since nature itself has placed in us this conviction. In fact, everyone is concerned with life after death. This is, for Cicero, the surest argument in favor of immortality, even if he does not hesitate to support it with traditional Platonic proofs*.
>
> > – quote taken from *A History of Ancient Philosophy III: Systems of the Hellenistic Age*, by Giovanni Reale. Reale was an Italian philosopher who published his five-volume tome in 1975. Blame for this use of the English phrase "have a doubt about" may need to be placed on the shoulders of the translator, John R. Catan; however, given Catan's [rather impressive resume](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&field-author=John%20R.%20Catan&page=1&rh=n:283155,p_27:John%20R.%20Catan), I'm not inclined to categorize this as a rookie mistake.

---

Now, back to the original question:

> To my (British) ear, it **never** sounds correct to say you have a doubt about something. [*emphasis added*]

*Never* is a strong word. I've offered five quotes ranging from the 19th century to the 21st century, ranging from theologians to atheists, ranging in context from philosophy to fiction, from respected authors with roots on either side of the Atlantic. None of them caused me to bristle as though I just heard fingernails scraping on a chalkboard, and none of them made me immediately question if the author was a speaker of Indian English.

*Never* is a word that spurs pedantic analysis. I usually try to avoid it. In this case, I think there **are** times when *have a doubt about something* sounds acceptable, and supporting examples can be found if you're willing to do the research.

Comment: Oh dear! Per [my recent comment above](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/i-have-a-doubt-about-whether-this-sentence-is-acceptable-english/18331?noredirect=1#comment33627_4727), I wasn't really expecting any "non-Indians" to say the question in the title was "acceptable". Do you perhaps live in an area with a high proportion of Indians? Apparently your parliamentary citation was by Viscount Colville of Culross (born in British Columbia, died 2010), in the context of a debate about multiculturalism in Bristol, just after Baroness Corston quoted Mahatma Gandhi. Subliminal suggestion?

Comment: My two cents: I can sort of *convince* myself that it's okay, but intuitively it doesn't sound right to me as an AmE speaker.  And for what it's worth, I *have* spent a lot of time with Indian speakers.

Comment: @snailplane: The parents living in two of the five closest neighbouring houses to mine are all Indian/Pakistani, and another has Indian parents living across town. But they're all "well-integrated", after living in the UK for decades. Although there are limits to how much they can lose their *accents*, in my experience they quickly and willingly learn to avoid *constructions* which might have been standard in their native land, but are viewed as "odd" by Brits in their "adopted" land.

Comment: @Fumble - Oh dear indeed. I work on a college campus in the U.S., which means that I do see Indians on a daily or at least weekly basis, but most of my day-to-day conversation happens with people who speak using a Midwestern U.S. dialect. Anyhow, I've amended my answer to provide a few more examples.

Comment: @J.R.: It certainly isn't *my* downvote! Quite possibly I've downvoted other things you've posted, but I don't see how it would make sense to downvote a native speaker for saying some particular usage "doesn't grate". What you personally do or don't find "natural" must surely be entirely up to you. I could only downvote, say, an assertion that *significant numbers of other people* felt the same, if there was no evidence to back that up. But in this specific case, even 294 (apparently, mainly Indian) instances of *"I have a doubt about this"* are nothing compared to 7100 for the plural form.

Comment: @Fumble - The Ngram I linked to shows that the singular form is rare, and the plural form is common. Had your question asked, "Which is more common?" that would have been a slam dunk (then again, that wouldn't have been a very interesting discussion, either). Oh, and about the downvote, I guessed it was probably someone else, but there would have been no hard feelings either way – I don't have any doubt about that.

Comment: Well, I seem to recall we've disagreed before on what I see as the underlying *general* point here. I don't think ELL (as opposed to ELU) should give any significant attention to usages that are relatively *very* rare (GB claims 23800 instances of *but he has doubts*, but the *only* instance of the singular isn't exactly comparable anyway). So far as I'm concerned, competent speakers can use whatever forms they like, but learners would be wise to learn the "standard" forms and not be tempted to dabble in "marginal" usages.

Comment: @snailplane: That seems perfectly reasonable to me. Obviously there's nothing in J.R's answer that's actually *incorrect*, so it should not have been downvoted. My only concern is that the *implications* of "doesn't grate on my American ear" should not be taken too much to heart. Whilst it may not grate on *some* native speakers' ears, it will on others. But so long as there's a clear voting preference for Andrew's answer on this page, I suppose my original "Oh dear!" comment is a bit OTT.

Comment: Perhaps this wouldn't be such a tough issue if doubts weren't so hard to delimit and enumerate. I may have doubts about that email promising me millions if I would just wire a few grand to that down-on-his-luck stranger in Nigeria, but it would be hard for me to quantify what those doubts are, one-by-one. However, there may be contexts where something is more believable, save for one nagging doubt. The fictional detective [Columbo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo), for example, often seemed to have a [single?] doubt about an alibi, prompting his famous "One more thing..." line.

Answer (score 2):

> I doubt it.

meaning you don't really believe what you were being told. If you believe you are right, that's not mental uncertainty.

> No doubt.

This is a set phrase similar to absolutely or for sure.

In your phrase

> I have a doubt on my construction...

I would say

> I have **my doubts** on my construction...

although this one seems to be mental uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard "I have a doubt about [some technical subject]" when the proper phrase would be "I have a question about [some technical subject]".  "doubt" implies some sort of distrust or uneasiness, where what is actually happening is the person is merely missing some information and would like an answer.  Not sure where "doubt" and "question" have gotten to be synonyms, but the mis-use seems to come almost exclusively from non-native speakers.